# Hit fx with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am following a [video](https://youtu.be/LXz92pkCRTY?si=ax9CGY7m6nosOsBd&t=16) about a hit effect with Geometry Nodes.

The hit effect shown in the video is created by a bunch of transparent planes and some particles. The one-minute video is not a tutorial, but rather a process documentation with a few keywords. The first part shows the creation of the image textures with [Material Maker](https://www.materialmaker.org/), then the creation of the explosion in Blender with Geometry Nodes, and finally the addition of the animated particles.

Although, I basically got stuck pretty early because of my lack of knowledge in Geometry Nodes and I'd appreciate if someone could tell me which nodes to use and why. This is what I got so far:

Geometry Nodes:
[image: geometry node tree]

Material Shader:
[image: material shader nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar question about this video but it was closed or deleted because it was too broad. Let's focus on the middle part here:

**The Creation of The Explosion With a Bunch of Planes**

This effect can be created with a few *Geometry Nodes* and a material. In my humble opinion, it would be easier to use one or more planes for the instances. This has the advantage that you already have a UV map and can easily set the origin and the material and saves you a few nodes. It would also be easier to use an individual image texture for each "explosion variant" instead of four variants on one image. This would save you the UV vector math calculations. But well, let's stick to the video.

**1. The Creation The Plane Instances**

You have already done this with a *Grid* node. Here, it's important that you need to set the origin to the bottom center of the plane so the images are aligned properly. Use the *Set Position* node with offset y: `0.5 m` the get the origin right.

As you have already done and as described in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/primitives/grid.html#outputs), you also need a *Set Material* node to assign the material and a *Store Named Attribute* node to save the generated UV map in an attribute. It's `uvs` in the example.

Finally, create the instances on a point cloud with a *Points* node and an *Instance on Points* node. The first node creates several points, all at the same position and the other node places the planes on the points. The origin determines the position during creation, which means that all planes are stacked in the same place.

Last but not least, add a *Random Value* node and connect it with the *Rotation* input of the *Instance on Points* node. Set the *Min* and *Max* to `-pi` and `pi` (Blender will replace it by `3.142`). Now the planes are rotated by min -180° and max 180° in all directions.

[image: geometry nodes]

**2. The Animation of The Explosion**

This is just done by increasing the *Scale* value of the *Instance on Points* input from 0 to ... however large you want it to be. I've done it with a [driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/usage.html). It's created automatically when you enter a value that starts with a `#`. Then the input box turns purple. Try `#min((frame/25)**2.5, 20)`. It scales the planes exponentially from a very low scale to a maximum of 20. There is another driver in the material shader to control the transparency.

**3. The Material Shader**

Here you need assign each instance plane a random image texture. In the video an image as four variants on it, so it requires some math to shift the UVs and do the random pick.

Fading out is done by increasing the transparency in the material shader using a driver (expression is simply `#frame`) and two *Map Range* node plus a *Float Curve* to let it glow for a long time and then let it go out quickly.

[image: material shader]

If you want to try at home, here's the used [image texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouqAf.png). It's a white image on transparent/white background = nothing to see.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much for your help !